# Hypothesis testing: multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, spss

i need help with testing the following hypothesis:

H1: demographic variables influence the quality perception of French wines

I conducted an online survey that asked for the following demographic variables:
- age 
- gender
- income
- field of studies 
- level of education 
- years of prof. experience

The quality perception was measured by the following question:
"When compared to Japanese wine, French wine has higher quality." The participants then had to rate their level of agreement on a 5 point Likert scale.

In order to test my hypothesis (preferably with Excel, SPSS is also ok), I thought it makes sense to conduct a linear multiple regression. But I am unsure if it makes more sense to conduct a regression for each single variable instead?
How do I code them properly for a regression? For example, i have six categories for field of studies and coded them from 1-6, but i think this is wrong. Dummy vraibales are the way to go, right? How would I compute them in my case?
Besides, does it make sense to griup field of studies in less categories or does the number of categories not infleunce the outcome?

Thank you so so much for your help, I am a bit lost at the moment.

Comment: Is this question school work?

Comment: no it is not for school